# Use result obtained in one select query in other statement in MySQL Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am writing a stored procedure where I am fetching data from one table and based on that data I want to use that data in other manipulations. E.g.

```
select id,name,email,mobile,user_type from users
```

And based on the user_type I want to do further processing using id field . for E.g.,

```
if(user_type=1) 
   begin
        select * from some_table where Userid = id
   End
Else if (user_type=2)
  begin
      select * from some_other_table where Userid = id
  End
```

Can anyone provide me with basic syntax to do that

Answer (score 0):

You can `declare` variables in the procedure and then fill them using `SELECT ... INTO ... FROM` statement. Then those variables can be used within `IF THEN ELSE` expressions.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE test()
BEGIN
   DECLARE temp_id, temp_user_type INT;
   DECLARE temp_name, temp_email, temp_mobile VARCHAR(100);

   SELECT id,name,email,mobile,user_type 
   INTO temp_id, temp_name, temp_email, temp_mobile, temp_user_type FROM users WHERE id = 1;

   IF temp_user_type = 1 THEN 
        SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE Userid = temp_id     
   ELSEIF temp_user_type = 2 THEN
        SELECT * FROM some_other_table WHERE Userid = temp_id
   ELSE 
        --
   END IF;
END$$
```